# How can I target elements outside the angular app with protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I have an intro element that plays before the Angular app bootstraps.

```
<!-- need to target div below -->
<div id="intro"></div>
<!-- still bootstraping -->
<app-root></app-root>
```

I am using the following protractor spec provided in Angular-cli

```
describe('my App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage(); // default from angular cli
  });

  it(`should provide an intro div`, () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    const introDiv = element(by.id('intro'));
    expect(introDiv.isPresent()).toBe(true); // reports as false in protractor test
  });
});
```

I'm able to target elements inside the Angular App using the same 'it' function above, Why won't this work outside the Angular app and how can I target elements in index.html?

### Update:

I've done further testing and wanted to log this in the question just for reference:

Not mentioned above, I actually have angular remove the intro div as it's fullscreen coverage.

Thanks to the reference of the Protractor documentation provided by Ernst Zwingli, it tells me that Protractor automatically applies [browser.waitForAngular()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular) command before every WebDriver action.

So the test above that tried to target the intro div couldn't find it as it looked for it After angular bootstraped and removed the div.

I had created a temporary div in index.html that nothing touches. It is simply available with `element(by.id('find-me'))` even though it's outside Angular's app.

```
<div id="find-me"></div>

it(`is available after angular bootstraps and can be targeted with element()`, () => {
    const findMeDiv = element(by.id('find-me'));
    expect(findMeDiv.isPresent()).toBe(true);
  });
```

I finally was able to target the intro div by using the [browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngularEnabled) since it's available before Angular bootstraps. Although this only wait's for $http and $timeouts it seems to be enough to be able to target the div before bootstrap. I'm not sure if it totally cancels out `browser.waitForAngular()`.

(The difference with waitForAngular() waits for **rendering, http, timeouts** while the waitForAngularEnabled() is only concerned about **http** and **timeouts** - although the name similarity might suggest waitForAngularEnabled(false) totally cancels out waitForAngular() e.g. also including **rendering** and was not specified in docs).

```
<div id="intro"></div>

// Works
  it(`Found to be available if I use browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) since div is removed when Angular is ready`, () => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    const introDiv = element(by.id('intro'));
    expect(introDiv.isPresent()).toBe(true);
  });
```

So basically both Ernst Zwingli and Xotabu4 provided good insight as I needed `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` and could use the `element()` function to gain access to the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically should treat that part as `non-angular` and look up the elements by using the [Selenium WebDriver-methods](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver).

So, instead of `element(by.id('intro'))` use `browser.driver.findElement(by.id('intro'))`, which due to `browser.driver` uses the JavaScript/Vanilla `browser` instead of the Protractor `browser` and therefore works outside any angular-scope.

However, you need to give up your `expect()`-statement, because the Protractor `element(locator)` represents an `ElementArrayFinder`, while WebDriver-methods like `findElement()`, `getWebElement()` and similar, represent directly the WebElement (so they immediately execute the search for element and don't wait with it until code requires the real WebElement). [Read about here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder).

So in your case, with `findElement` you either get a WebDriver-Error, because the element is not present, or you get the WebElement, because it's there (no need to further check presence).

[Here the Selenium-Documentation](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebDriver.html) and [here a GitHub, that explains the use of Protractor in Non-Angular](https://github.com/sakshisingla/Protractor-Non-Angular-Tests/wiki/Creating-test-scripts-using-Protractor-for-non-angular-application)

**Bytheway**:

If the full page is Non-Angular, you need to switch off the Protractor ControlFlow with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` (this was earlier `ignoreSynchronization = true`, but don't use that anymore).

If only part of the page is Non-Angular you might not need to switch Protractor off, but you might need to explicitly take care of a synchronous execution (something for try & error)

**UPDATE**

Due to the comment I got, I feel the urge to link to some further information, that further prove my point (because Protractor <> Vanilla):

- [(protractor) `browser` <> (vanilla) `browser` // (protractor) `browser.driver` === (vanilla) `browser`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/webdriver-vs-protractor.md)
- [`element` = `[elementFinder]` but `element` <> `findElement`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md#actions)
- [example to show the difference](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.getWebElement)

Comment: ```element(by.id('intro')), use browser.driver.findElement(by.id('intro'))```

Searching of elements would be absolutely the same, except in first case 'waitForAngular()' would be made, check source code.
I believe we just need to wait for element a little

Comment: @Xotabu4 :  I think you're wrong. I updated my answer to better differentiate between vanilla and protractor

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answer both of you had given me, I'm able to target the div with element() and use to browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) to target it before angular bootstraps. : )